# Codesigning modified binaries (Apple Silicon/M1)

Tags: macos, codesign, apple-silicon

macOS on the M1 processor seems to prevent modified binaries from running. For instance, a simple C hello world:

```c
#import <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

If I compile this with Clang and run it, everything works as expected. However, if I go into a hex editor and change the `'H'` => `'h'` (or something else trivial), the the kernel immediately sends a `SIGKILL`, i.e.

```
➜  ~ ✗ ./a.out
[1]    943 killed     ./a.out
```

I assume this is due to the fact that there are heavier codesigning restrictions on the M1 (https://eclecticlight.co/2020/08/22/apple-silicon-macs-will-require-signed-code/), but if I try to sign the modified binary with a self-signed cert, I get a fairly non-descript error:

```
➜  ~ ✗ codesign -s zbaylin a.out
a.out: the codesign_allocate helper tool cannot be found or used
```

I know `codesign_allocate` is in my `PATH`, and I am able to sign *unmodified* executables, but any binary that has been modified refuses to sign.

Is there any way to sign these binaries, or disable the signature checks temporarily? I should mention that all of this works on my 2019 MacBook Pro (x86, obviously), so I think it has something to do with the M1 in particular.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a known bug in the `codesign` tool. To work around it, make a copy of your modified executable, sign the copy, then replace the original executable with the signed copy and it should work.

For more details, see [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/9082).